# How to encode passwords as SHA512 in symfony3?

Tags: symfony, hash, passwords, sha512

we store our users in a database, the passwords are stored as SHA512 hashed strings. The format is: `$6$rounds=5000$[salt]$[hash]` We use an old, self written php method for that with `crypt()`.

Now I want to write a new app with symfony 3.3.1 and configured the bcrypt algorithm in the security.yml:

```
encoders:
    AppBundle\Entity\User:
        algorithm: bcrypt
```

The login works fine this way. I also try to save a new User and encode the password like this:

```
public function register(Request $request, UserPasswordEncoderInterface $encoder)
{
    $user = User();

    $form = $this->get('form.factory')->createNamed('register', UserRegistrationForm::class, $user, [
        'action' => $this->generateUrl('register')
    ]);

    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $password = $encoder->encodePassword($user, $user->getPassword());
        $user->setPassword($password);
        ...
}
```

But the password isn't encoded in the needed format, I can't login as the newly created User. Any tips how I have to configure symfony3 to encode passwords in the `$6$rounds=5000...` format? Or do I have to write a custom password encoder for that?

Comment: The question about encoding is not so clear but, are you sure you have created/instanciated the `new` User? `$user = new User();` or you have only a typo in the question?

Comment: Consider configuring the encoder to use sha512 per the manual: https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html#full-default-configuration Though I suspect you will end up writing a custom encoder to match your existing algorithm.

Comment: I created a new User object and bound it onto the register form, sorry that this wasn't shown in my example code. I edited my example accordingly.

And I tried to use algorithm: sha512 with iterations: 5000 and encode_as_base64 true and false, but the password always had a wrong format.

So a custom password encoder it is... :(